# AWS The Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy header has been ignored, because the URL's origin was untrustworthy

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have started a django app on an EC2 instance and I have added my static files(css, js, etc) onto a S3 bucket. After many hours last night I managed to get the static inages to load onto the pages when i viewed the EC2 public address Happy days.

But now i keep getting this error: I keep getting this error when i view inspect a web page "The Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy header has been ignored, because the URL's origin was untrustworthy. It was defined either in the final response or a redirect. Please deliver the response using the HTTPS protocol. You can also use the 'localhost' origin instead"

And none of my static images are loading. I can't find anything online related to this exact error message, there are some variants which lead to dead ends. does anyone know what is going on?

Whats weird is if i run my django app on my personal pc, then the error does not show when i inspect BUT the static images also do not load.

When i run the django app on the ec2 instance, then I get the error message with the static images still not loading. So i dont think the error is affecting the static images from loading, i.e they're 2 separate issues.

But last night all of this was working so i dunno whats happened.

Comment: Could you upload your settings.py

Comment: added settings.py and env file. There;s a lot of commented lines as i've been trialing different solutions with no luck lol but these are the settings I had when everything was working last night

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem? Please share if you have a solution

Comment: @ДаниэльСеидов Yes, i did a lot of trial and error but if I remember correctly, I had to change the firewall settings in the linux ec2 instance that was causing issues. That's why it would work when connecting via local host (personal pc) but not work when using the public xxx.ec2..amazon.com link. So make sure firewall settings on the ec2 instance are correct.

Answer (score 2):

One of the serious bugs I have ever encountered.
I got it solved by adding the following setting in your setting.py
`SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY=None`
https://django.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/settings.html#std-setting-SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY

Why did I do that? because the default setting of same origin generated that error persistently. But I know it’s a security concern and perhaps someone who has done system security can give further advice.

Then you if you are not sone yet with your troubles as I was, you probably will have db connection issues, i.e, no error thrown but somehow the app does not connect. reading the docs, django recommends turning
`SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False`
Hopefully it works for you.